I want nothing but the best for my children. (what's the best here?)

I want nothing but the best for my children.

I found the sentence above in a dictionary. What does the phrase "the bast" mean?

OP has asked the meaning of "the best" in:

I want nothing but the best for my children.

The sentence does not specify what "the best" means. In this context, "the best" is open to interpretation, depending on the speaker's perspective, values, and priorities.
It could refer to concrete things like education or health, or more abstract ideas like happiness or success.
Which parent doesn't want the best for their children?.
While "the best" might be impossible to define or achieve, the sentiment expresses a strong desire for the children's well-being.
This ambiguity is what makes the phrase versatile — it allows the listener or reader to project their own understanding of what "the best" means.

best noun the most excellent in a group of things or people: My tastes are simple - I only like the best. He wanted the best for his children - good schools, a nice house, and trips abroad. Cambridge Dictionary

@MichaelHarvey Is it in the dictionary?  He wanted the best for his children - good schools, a nice house, and trips abroad. I am unable to see. "The best" is relative. The best for an ordinary accountant is not same as that of Elon Musk.

On my PC I can go to this page https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/best and scroll down past the first two meanings (adjective, adverb) to the noun meaning, where I can see the (to me, deplorably materialist) one about schools, houses, and trips abroad.

Don't mention that fascist Elon Musk to me!

I would say that while a context could provide an implied meaning (Pokemon theme, "I want to be the very best" = trainer), the OP has shown a case where context could be intentionally vague. @MichaelHarvey while the entry you cite is certainly valid, it mentions "things or people," one could perhaps salvage a less materialistic meaning if "things" can include intangibles. Certainly I want the best for my children, but would be quite surprised if they wind up with literally the best houses, jobs, or even partners. Rather...

... Rather, I want the best outcomes for them; I want them to be happy, stable, wise, kind, resilient, etc. Arguably, this means wanting the best of them for them. If these goals count as "things," or if these visions of their future selves count as "people," then the definition stands; if not, we must seek out another, because this is definitely a valid usage, right alongside the entitled "Only the best for my widdle sweetums" one.

I want a golden toilet. Not just 14K, mind you. Only the best.

It is a common trope in the UK that vulgar, flashy 'self-made' fathers will say 'Only the best for my little princess!' about pony clubs, ski holidays, vacations in the Maldives, new iPhone every year, top-tier private school, etc.
